# R- Removing missing value in multiple vector

Tags: r

As the question, I want to remove missing value in 2 vectors which have missing value in it, for example

```
x<- c(1, 2, NA, 6, NA)
y<- c("a", NA, "b", "c", NA)
```

then I use

```
good<- complete.cases(x, y)
```

then when I subset x and y

```
> x[good]
[1] 1 6
> y[good]
[1] "a" "c"
```

Why the element 2 and "b" are missing while it suppose to appear in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete.cases function returns an index to locations where NEITHER x or y is NA.  If you just want to remove Nas in a single vector, look at the is.na() function.

Comment: Thank you, I've got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
x <- x[!is.na(x)]
y <- y[!is.na(x)]
```

This removes the NA values per vector.